# Disable Delete for specific records of inline form Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a stacked inline form in my admin.py:

```
class XYZInline(admin.TabularInline):

   model = XYZ
   readonly_fields = ['modify', 'approver_page']
   form = XYZForm
   extra = 0
```

And I have it initialized in another model on the admin.py:

```
class SomeOhterModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [XYZInline]
```

What I want to do is disable the Delete checkbox in the Inline form for specific form records after checking the value of some of the inputs on the records of the form. If a certain input value matches, we disable the checkbox, otherwise we don't. How can we do this? And how can we check for input values of some of the fields of the form?

Some stackoverflow examples suggest adding a `self.can_delete=False` to the form initializer method. However, that would disable delete for all the form records of the Inline model.

Comment: I´m looking for the same. Not the best solution but here it is something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129846/has-delete-permission-gets-parent-instance-in-django-admin-inline